# Ansible use variable inside a variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use variable inside a variable

vars:

```
env: dev  
groupname: (Dynamic variable which comes as stdout of ansible task )
```

task:

```
- name: var to trim  
  set_fact:  
    trim_var: "{{ groupname.split(\"test-{{ env }}-\") }}"
```

But its not replacing env with dev. can some one please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never nest `{{...}}` markers. You're already inside a Jinja context, so you can just write variables normally:

```
- name: var to trim  
  set_fact:  
    trim_var: "{{ groupname.split('test-' ~ env ~ '-') }}"
```

Note that the Jinja `~` operator behaves like `+`, but it will convert its operands to strings first (which doesn't matter in this case, but is quite useful if you're dealing with variables that are not strings).